# Remove index.php from URL in CI?

Tags: codeigniter

I removed index.php from the URL in CodeIgniter. I have already changed the .htaccess file        data. But I want to know that is there any other way to remove the index.php from the URL or through any other .htaccess data. Means this is only a way or not.

In .htaccess file I wrote this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Make sure you have enabled **rewrite_module** on your Apache modules

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|indexcp\.php?|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/.-]+)$ index.php?/welcome/$1
```

Open config.php :-

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';  //your site name

$config['uri_protocol']= 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and do not forget to null index value in config file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>                                     

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).